# Azure AD V2 PowerShell - exclude a property in output

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm using Azure AD V2 Powershell module and want to create a very quick report of users/groups/membership for a B2C tenant.

How can I exclude the ObjectIds from the output to the file generated from the following powershell code?

```
Get-AzureADGroup | Out-File -filepath $outputFilePath -Append
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `-ExcludeProperty` parameter in the `Select-Object` cmdlet:

```
Get-AzureADGroup | 
Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ObjectId |
Out-File -filepath $outputFilePath -Append
```